# Array to string conversion while passing query data(array) in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Array to string conversion while passing query data(array) in where clause. I tried enough so now i'm going to scared of. I tried to to replace `->result()` with `->row()` in `$ord = "query"` but no sake. I  Please any body help me, what should i do now. Thank you. Here is my code.

```
public function order_join()
{
$ord = $this->db->query('SELECT `Order_ID` FROM `order` WHERE `DateTime` = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM `order`)')->result(); 
$query = "SELECT a.Order_ID, a.User_ID,a.Pro_ID, a.Price as Total_Amount, SUM(b.Amount) 
            as Total_Amount_Recieved, (a.Price - SUM(b.Amount)) AS Remaining_Amount 
            FROM `order` a JOIN `payments` b ON a.Order_ID = b.Order_ID WHERE a.Order_ID = '".$ord."' ";
return $this->db->query($query)->row();
```

}
and this is error. [image: Error]

Comment: `$ord` is an array.  You can't do `"a.Order_ID = '".$ord."'"`.

Comment: Then what should i do now..

Comment: How many rows does that first query return?  You'll have to loop over the array to get each `Order_ID`, or you can get the first with `$ord[0]->Order_ID`.

Comment: First query only returns me the single row...

Comment: Instead of return `$this->db->query($query)->row();` try `return $query->row_array()`

Comment: Then change `->result();` to `->row()->Order_ID;`

Comment: #wolfgang same error

Comment: Thank you #Rocket_Hazmat, it works... Thank you

Comment: Dear #Rocket, please answer here, that i should rate i